# differentiate between ipad contacts and sync contacts which is using Microsoft exchange and other server in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have tried many times to differentiate between iPad contacts and other sync contacts from a different server but I haven't been able to find a way to differentiate. How can we get the source? I'd like the account name or user name from where we synced contacts in iPad or iPhone.

```
CFTypeRef sourceTypeEx; CFArrayRef sources = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllSources(addressBook); CFIndex sourceCount = CFArrayGetCount(sources);

for (CFIndex i = 0 ; i < sourceCount; i++){  
    ABRecordRef currentSource = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(sources, i);
    sourceTypeEx = ABRecordCopyValue(currentSource, kABSourceTypeExchange);
    NSString *obj = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",sourceTypeEx];    
}
```